# images not appearing in gridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I have a gridView here:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_drag_and_drop_app"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#00FF00">

            <!-- Editext for Search -->
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/Search_applications"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvApps"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    />
    </LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLinkToPersonalize"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/Personalize"
        android:textColor="#21dbd4"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

<GridView 
android:id="@+id/GRIDVIEW1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:columnWidth="60dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
 >  

</GridView>

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/trash_can"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/trashcanDescription_Delete"
    android:padding="40dip"
    android:src="@drawable/trashcan"
    android:visibility="gone" >
</ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and then have this coding:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

IMPORTS

public class Drag_and_Drop_App extends Activity {

//For GridView
private int draggedIndex = -1;
private BaseAdapter adapterGV;
ArrayList<Integer> drawables = new ArrayList<Integer>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // set layout for the main screen
    setContentView(R.layout.drag_and_drop_app);

    // GridView
    Log.d("GridView", "onCreate called");
    drawables.add(R.drawable.pattern1);
    drawables.add(R.drawable.pattern2);
    android.widget.GridView gridView = (android.widget.GridView) findViewById(R.id.GRIDVIEW1);

    // Instance of Adapter Class
    gridView.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(this));
   // gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
```

and this adapter:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

IMPORTS

public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContextGV;

// Keep all Images in array list
public ArrayList<Integer> drawables = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// Constructor
public GridViewAdapter(Context c){
    mContextGV = c;
}

@Override
// How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter
public int getCount() {
    return drawables.size();
}

@Override
// Get the data item associated with the specified position in the
// data set
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return drawables.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Try to reuse the views
    ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView;
    // if convert view is null then create a new instance else reuse it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new ImageView(mContextGV);
    }

    view.setImageResource(drawables.get(position));
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    view.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    view.setTag(String.valueOf(position));
    return view;
}

}
```

But the drawables pattern1 and pattern2 never show up in my gridView.

I made sure that the gridView onCreate() method is being called (which it is).

What can I do to fix this?

NEW CODING:
Drag_and_Drop_App:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // set layout for the main screen
    setContentView(R.layout.drag_and_drop_app);

    // GridView
    Log.d("D&D", "onCreate called");

    android.widget.GridView gridView = (android.widget.GridView) findViewById(R.id.GRIDVIEW1);

    // Instance of Adapter Class
    gridView.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(this));
   // gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
```

My gridViewAdapter:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

IMPORTS
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContextGV;

// Keep all Images in array list
public ArrayList<Integer> drawables = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// Constructor
public GridViewAdapter(Context c){
    mContextGV = c;
    Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "Constructor is set");
}

@Override
// How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter
public int getCount() {
    return drawables.size();
}

@Override
// Get the data item associated with the specified position in the
// data set
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return drawables.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Try to reuse the views
    ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView;
    // if convert view is null then create a new instance else reuse it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new ImageView(mContextGV);
        Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "new imageView added");
    }
    drawables.add(R.drawable.pattern1);
    Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "pattern1 added");

    drawables.add(R.drawable.pattern2);
    Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "pattern2 added");

    drawables.add(R.drawable.trashcan);
    Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "trashcan added");

    drawables.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "ic_launcher added");

    view.setImageResource(drawables.get(position));
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    view.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    view.setTag(String.valueOf(position));
    return view;
}

}
```

Comment: you pass don't pass your drawables list from `Drag_and_Drop_App` to your adapter

Comment: Ok, so how (or where is maybe the better question) should I go about adding the drawables? In the adapter? Or should I just change where my list is?

Comment: if you don't need to reuse your adapter, i suggest initializing your list in the adapter.

Comment: Ok so I took my adapter out of my Drag_and_Drop class and put things into my adapter (please check updated question above), but apparently, my logs for setting the pictures into the gridView aren't being called.

Comment: add these ids of your drawables in the constructor of your adapter. otherwise `getCount()` returns 0 and `getView()` never gets called, because the gridview thinks, there are 0 items.

Comment: This worked! All the images are appearing in the gridView now! Thanks! :DD

Comment: I had the same problem and all of a sudden it just started working. The same code nothing was changed.

Answer (score 0):

The closing tag of the gridview in the xml file

```
</gridview>
```

is before the imageview, therefore your image will not be in the gridView.

More generally speaking, if an image do not show, make sure you have the image with the resolution for the screen of the device you are using.

Comment: That imageview is for something else...the image I am trying to add to the gridView is the pattern1 and pattern2 in my second block of coding above

Comment: and the pattern images should be fine with the resolution part, that I know of

Comment: Please consider putting only the minimal useful code in your questions.

Comment: Regarding your question: you should use the drawable to populate an imageView which you add to the layout. (See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int) ) Alternatively, you can use the drawable as background of the layout. (See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int) )

Comment: I am trying to use the drawable for the gridView so that it shows up in the gridView. Please note my getView method of my adapter where I create a new imageView for each picture. I am adding the drawables (pattern1 and pattern2) to an ArrayList called drawables and then using that arrayList, I am populating the gridView. Hope this helps to clear up what I am trying to do

Comment: Haha it's ok, we are all a little tired today :P